# golang google cloud storage 403 forbidden

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to read files from Google cloud storage bucket throgh json credentials. If I run sam code from local It is working. But when I try from GKE pod then it giving 403 forbidden.

**Code sample**

```
            bkt := configs.GCPClient.Bucket(bucketName)
    it := bkt.Objects(ctx, nil)
    
    for {
        attrs, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            return files
        }
                    fmt.Println(attrs.Name)
    }
```

We got error 403 forbidden
**googleapi: Error 403: Caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist)., forbidden**

Comment: are you sure you're using the same JSON creds in the GKE pod? or have you verified it has mounted correctly

Comment: You don't need to use JSON creds on GKE. Have a look to workload identity.